# Does an element whose grandparent (but not direct parent) establishes a block formatting context, participate in that BFC?

Tags: css

If an element's grandparent establishes a BFC, but not its direct parent, does that element participate in its grandparent's BFC?

My guess is that it does. My logic is that the root html element establishes a BFC while the body element doesn't, and yet all children of body seem to participate in a BFC. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question dependent on a lot of variables unfortunately. The element root (html) does indeed create it however the context of the parent / child relationships impact within themselves as well. I'd suggest browsing [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) since your assumptions between grandparent -> parent -> child etc are relative in their usage between one another. So without more instance specifics we can't definitively say either way since `body` **could** in fact also create "BFC".

Comment: @ChrisW. why is it broad? the question is clear: the grandparent establish a BFC and the parent not so he asking the child is a part of that BFC. The anser is yes

Comment: @TemaniAfif I guess I was hung up on the portion between the context of the html vs the body statement since body could but also could not as it seemed the first sentence may be oversimplified but the second eluded to a different potential context however I yield to your interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

> If an element's grandparent establishes a BFC, but not its direct parent, does that element participate in its grandparent's BFC?

Yes it does. Here is a basic example to illustrate:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  float:left;
}

body {
  border:1px solid green;
}

html {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

The body doesn't create a BFC and the html does. For this reason the float element is within the blue boundary and not the green one. Don't forget that one way to *clear* float is to create a BFC that's why I am using a float to demonstrate the existence or not of a BFC.

the same logic apply if you have a deeper structure:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

html {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid purple
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

> Formatting contexts affect layout, but typically, we create a new block formatting context for the positioning and clearing floats rather than changing the layout, because an element that establishes a new block formatting context will:
>
> - contain internal floats.
> - exclude external floats.
> - suppress margin collapsing.